# Hide Detailed Row in SSRS When Toggled Item are collapsed

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I went through many post on **SO** but not find the suitable solution to the problem

I have a tablix and I have groups and toggled on `Run`,`Task Name` and `Procedure Name`. when the groups are collapsed one detailed row after `procedure name` is visible.

> What I want is to hide entire row when toggled is collapsed and will show when it is expanded. how to achive this
>   I want to hide all information from operation to status columns in tablix when toggled is collapsed.

Here is the tablix I am dealing with
[image]

@user3540780 I have already done that groupings
here is what I have done 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up four groups
Dimensions, Task Name, Procedure Name and Load.

Task Name is toggled by Dimension,
Procedure Name is toggled By Task Name,
Load is toggled by Procedure Name.

Load needs to be a grouping at detail line level simply grouping on all the fields in your detail section.

Set up your toggles in the **Row Groups** window at the bottom of the designer screen. If you have added the groups correctly there will be a dashed grouping line between the Operation column and the remaining columns. (You need to have selected a cell in the tablix to see these)

You will find that the whole detail line will be toggled

Comment: can you post a picture of the tablix in design view

Comment: You need to select a cell in the tablix before capturing the image so I can see the dashed grouping lines